# Import mail content from outlook into website

Tags: vba, vbscript, outlook

I have a list of information about one product and it will be imported to that product company website by using a VBA code.

The process should happen from outlook (Mail content) and Internet explorer (product Website) with the VBA code.

Comment: This isn't actually a question. Please edit it to make clear what you are asking. Also it is usually required to show research effort before asking for help. Please detail what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macro code (VBA or VBScript) is a client's feature. It can't be run in the browser. However, you may consider developing a Mail App (JS, HTML) which can be run in the browser as well (Outlook).